# Julia massively outperforms Delphi. Obsolete asm code by Delphi compiler?

Tags: delphi, julia

I wrote a simple for loop in Delphi.
The same program is 7.6 times faster in Julia 1.6.

```
procedure TfrmTester.btnForLoopClick(Sender: TObject);
VAR
   i, Total, Big, Small: Integer;
   s: string;
begin   
  TimerStart;

   Total:= 0;
   Big  := 0;
   Small:= 0;
   for i:= 1 to 1000000000 DO    //1 billion
    begin
      Total:= Total+1;
      if Total > 500000
      then Big:= Big+1
      else Small:= Small+1;
    end;

 s:= TimerElapsedS;
 //here code to show Big/Small on the screen
end;
```

The ASM code seems decent to me:

```
TesterForm.pas.111: TimerStart;
007BB91D E8DE7CF9FF       call TimerStart
TesterForm.pas.113: Total:= 0;
007BB922 33C0             xor eax,eax
007BB924 8945F4           mov [ebp-$0c],eax
TesterForm.pas.114: Big  := 0;
007BB927 33C0             xor eax,eax
007BB929 8945F0           mov [ebp-$10],eax
TesterForm.pas.115: Small:= 0;
007BB92C 33C0             xor eax,eax
007BB92E 8945EC           mov [ebp-$14],eax
TesterForm.pas.**116**: for i:= 1 to 1000000000 DO    //1 billion
007BB931 C745F801000000   mov [ebp-$08],$00000001
TesterForm.pas.118: Total:= Total+1;
007BB938 FF45F4           inc dword ptr [ebp-$0c]
TesterForm.pas.119: if Total > 500000
007BB93B 817DF420A10700   cmp [ebp-$0c],$0007a120
007BB942 7E05             jle $007bb949
TesterForm.pas.120: then Big:= Big+1
007BB944 FF45F0           inc dword ptr [ebp-$10]
007BB947 EB03             jmp $007bb94c
TesterForm.pas.121: else Small:= Small+1;
007BB949 FF45EC           inc dword ptr [ebp-$14]
TesterForm.pas.122: end;
007BB94C FF45F8           inc dword ptr [ebp-$08]
TesterForm.pas.**116**: for i:= 1 to 1000000000 DO    //1 billion
007BB94F 817DF801CA9A3B   cmp [ebp-$08],$3b9aca01
007BB956 75E0             jnz $007bb938
TesterForm.pas.124: s:= TimerElapsedS;
007BB958 8D45E8           lea eax,[ebp-$18]
```

How can it be that Delphi has such a pathetic score compared with Julia?
Can I do anything to improve the code generated by the compiler?

**Info**

My Delphi 10.4.2 program is Win32 bit. Of course, I run in "Release" mode :)
[image]

[image]

But the ASM code above is for the "Debug" version because I don't know how to pause the execution of the program when I run an optimized EXE file. But the difference between a Release and a Debug exe is pretty small (1.8 vs 1.5 sec). Julia does it in 195ms.

**More discussions**

1. I do have to mention that when you run the code in Julia for the first time, its time is ridiculous high, because Julia is JIT, so it has to compile the code first. The compilation time (since it is "one-time") was not included in the measurement.
2. Also, as AmigoJack commented, Delphi code will run pretty much everywhere, while Julia code will probably only run in computers that have a modern CPU to support all those new/fancy instructions. I do have small tools that I produced back in 2004 and still run today.
3. Whatever code Julia produces cannot be delivered to "customers" unless that have Julia installed.

Anyway, all these being said, it is sad that that Delphi compiler is so outdated.

4. I ran other tests, finding the shortest and longest string in a list of strings is 10x faster in Delphi than Julia. Allocating small blocks of memory (10000x10000x4 bytes) has the same speed.
5. As AhnLab mentioned, I run pretty "dry" tests. I guess a full program that performs more complex/realistic tasks needs to be written and see at the end of the program if Julia still outperforms Delphi 7x.

---

**Update**

Ok, the Julia code seems totally alien to me. Seems to use more modern ops:

```
; ┌ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:4 within `for_fun`
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $96, %rsp
        vmovdqa %xmm11, -16(%rbp)
        vmovdqa %xmm10, -32(%rbp)
        vmovdqa %xmm9, -48(%rbp)
        vmovdqa %xmm8, -64(%rbp)
        vmovdqa %xmm7, -80(%rbp)
        vmovdqa %xmm6, -96(%rbp)
        movq    %rcx, %rax
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:8 within `for_fun`
; │┌ @ range.jl:5 within `Colon`
; ││┌ @ range.jl:354 within `UnitRange`
; │││┌ @ range.jl:359 within `unitrange_last`
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
; │└└└
        jle     L80
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl within `for_fun`
        movq    %rdx, %rcx
        sarq    $63, %rcx
        andnq   %rdx, %rcx, %r9
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:13 within `for_fun`
        cmpq    $8, %r9
        jae     L93
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl within `for_fun`
        movl    $1, %r10d
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        xorl    %r11d, %r11d
        jmp     L346
L80:
        xorl    %edx, %edx
        xorl    %r11d, %r11d
        xorl    %r9d, %r9d
        jmp     L386
L93:    movabsq $9223372036854775800, %r8       # imm = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF8
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:13 within `for_fun`
        andq    %r9, %r8
        leaq    1(%r8), %r10
        movabsq $.rodata.cst32, %rcx
        vmovdqa (%rcx), %ymm1
        vpxor   %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
        movabsq $.rodata.cst8, %rcx
        vpbroadcastq    (%rcx), %ymm2
        movabsq $1023787240, %rcx               # imm = 0x3D05C0E8
        vpbroadcastq    (%rcx), %ymm3
        movabsq $1023787248, %rcx               # imm = 0x3D05C0F0
        vpbroadcastq    (%rcx), %ymm5
        vpcmpeqd        %ymm6, %ymm6, %ymm6
        movabsq $1023787256, %rcx               # imm = 0x3D05C0F8
        vpbroadcastq    (%rcx), %ymm7
        movq    %r8, %rcx
        vpxor   %xmm4, %xmm4, %xmm4
        vpxor   %xmm8, %xmm8, %xmm8
        vpxor   %xmm9, %xmm9, %xmm9
        nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl within `for_fun`
L224:
        vpaddq  %ymm2, %ymm1, %ymm10
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:10 within `for_fun`
        vpxor   %ymm3, %ymm1, %ymm11
        vpcmpgtq        %ymm11, %ymm5, %ymm11
        vpxor   %ymm3, %ymm10, %ymm10
        vpcmpgtq        %ymm10, %ymm5, %ymm10
        vpsubq  %ymm11, %ymm0, %ymm0
        vpsubq  %ymm10, %ymm4, %ymm4
        vpaddq  %ymm11, %ymm8, %ymm8
        vpsubq  %ymm6, %ymm8, %ymm8
        vpaddq  %ymm10, %ymm9, %ymm9
        vpsubq  %ymm6, %ymm9, %ymm9
        vpaddq  %ymm7, %ymm1, %ymm1
        addq    $-8, %rcx
        jne     L224
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:13 within `for_fun`
        vpaddq  %ymm8, %ymm9, %ymm1
        vextracti128    $1, %ymm1, %xmm2
        vpaddq  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
        vpshufd $238, %xmm1, %xmm2              # xmm2 = xmm1[2,3,2,3]
        vpaddq  %xmm2, %xmm1, %xmm1
        vmovq   %xmm1, %r11
        vpaddq  %ymm0, %ymm4, %ymm0
        vextracti128    $1, %ymm0, %xmm1
        vpaddq  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0
        vpshufd $238, %xmm0, %xmm1              # xmm1 = xmm0[2,3,2,3]
        vpaddq  %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0
        vmovq   %xmm0, %rdx
        cmpq    %r8, %r9
        je      L386
L346:
        leaq    1(%r9), %r8
        nop
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:10 within `for_fun`
; │┌ @ operators.jl:378 within `>`
; ││┌ @ int.jl:83 within `<`
L352:
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        cmpq    $500000, %r10                   # imm = 0x7A120
        seta    %cl
        cmpq    $500001, %r10                   # imm = 0x7A121
; │└└
        adcq    $0, %rdx
        addq    %rcx, %r11
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:13 within `for_fun`
; │┌ @ range.jl:837 within `iterate`
        incq    %r10
; ││┌ @ promotion.jl:468 within `==`
        cmpq    %r10, %r8
; │└└
        jne     L352
; │ @ Julia_vs_Delphi.jl:17 within `for_fun`
L386:
        movq    %r9, (%rax)
        movq    %rdx, 8(%rax)
        movq    %r11, 16(%rax)
        vmovaps -96(%rbp), %xmm6
        vmovaps -80(%rbp), %xmm7
        vmovaps -64(%rbp), %xmm8
        vmovaps -48(%rbp), %xmm9
        vmovaps -32(%rbp), %xmm10
        vmovaps -16(%rbp), %xmm11
        addq    $96, %rsp
        popq    %rbp
        vzeroupper
        retq
        nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Comment: Some compilers may skip the loop if there is no visible outcome. Try to write `Small,Big or total` after the loop.

Comment: The loop check is done at the end, which makes line 116 appear twice.

Comment: @LURD - Now do print the numbers and they are correct. I get this: (1000000000, 500000, 999500000)

Comment: Could Julia lie about its measurements? I have to test that. The ASM code generated by Delphi is very nice. I don't know how much you can improve it to get a 7.6x increase in speed. That number is just crazy!

Comment: Which actual Delphi compiler version against which actual Julia compiler version? Those are **important details**. Try the recent FPCompiler and old Turbo Pascal compilers, too, unless this questions aims at something totally different than comparing apples (any Delphi compiler) with oranges (any Julia compiler).

Comment: "_Recent_" is a relative term. When in 3 months someone is reading these comments/your question it will be even harder to figure out the **actual** version number. And please edit it into your question, avoiding linebreaks, because they are always eaten in case you forgot to notice.

Comment: That means Julia compiles processor generation dependent (I'm sure you mean [Op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode)codes, not [Opp](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=opp)onents). Compile both in a VM that emulates a much older CPU. In other words: on which hardware would the Julia binary not run anymore when the Delphi binary would?

Comment: Both Julia and Delphi are compiling in 32bit mode? Because, if you compile in 64bit mode, of course you go faster. Quite a bit at that (that's why memory alignment is at 64bits)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting correct timing? When I test your loop code on my 18 year old computer with AMD FX-8350 CPU I'mg getting time measurements between 190 ms to 900 ms. I perform multiple measurements since code execution is so fast that sometimes CPU doesn't even ramp up to full speed. I use [TStopWatch](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) for measuring execution time...

Comment: ... If you do to make sure to never call [TStopWatch.StartNew](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch.StartNew) as there is bug in it which then results in wrong reported times.

Comment: I assume you’re doing multiple trials, not just a single run? Also remember to take the maximum time from a set of trials, don’t use the mean.

Comment: @rhody - Yes. For Delphi, I do have the compiler optimizations on, the process is set to max priority and I do run the code multiple times. But the difference between these runs is almost insignificant. For Julia, the library that is doing the timing already runs the tests multiple times.

Comment: @SilverWarior - I do use TStopWatch. I didn't know about that bug (can you link to it please). I just changed my code yesterday from Start to StartNew :( I guess I have to revert.

Comment: @SilverWarior - I get always the same result (no more than 5% deviation). But I set the process to: SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess, REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS). I had until recently EXACTLY the same CPU as you. Now the mainboard is dead. I use a laptop with newer Intel CPU. But compared with the AMD FX-8350 8x 4.2GHz it is like a small kitten compared to a bulldog.

Comment: @SilverWarior - PS: Believe me, you don't need a timer. You can see the program freezing for 2 seconds. So, the time reported by TStopWatch seems right. I do know that Intel CPUs, compared to AMD CPU have problems ramping up. So, this might be an issue. Although 1.5 seconds should be enough to ramp up.In Julia's case, the JIT might have already put the CPU in "high gear". Too bad, my old PC (FX-8350) is dead. RIP.  I will have to run the loop for much longer - but if you compare the new and shiny CPU instructions Julia is using... it might totally explain the difference.

Comment: Well reading a little bit about Julia it seems that it is also capable of compiling GPU native code. And since GPU's are much better at crunching numbers it would mean that if Julia is smart enough to move math calculations to GPU and keep logic on CPU it might beat pretty much any other programming language that runs only on CPU.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by noting that there is no reason for an optimizing compiler to actually perform the loop, at present Delphi and Julia output similar assembler that actually run through the loop but the compilers could in the future just skip the loop and assign the values. Microbenchmarks are tricky.

The difference seems to be that Julia makes use of [SIMD instructions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) which makes perfect sense for such loop (~8x speedup makes perfect sense depending on your CPU).

You could have a look at [this blog post](https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/07/10/simd-assembly-optimization/) for thoughts on SIMD in Delphi.

---

Although this is not the main point of the answer, I'll expand a bit on the possibility to remove the loop altogether. I don't know for sure what the Delphi specification says but in many compiled languages, including Julia ("just-ahead-of-time"), the compiler could simply figure out the state of the variables after the loop and replace the loop with that state. Have a look at the following C++ code ([compiler explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KfhzdzGx4)):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
void loop() {
    long total = 0, big = 0, small = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        total++;
        if (total > 50) {
            big++;
        } else {
            small++;
        }
    }
    std::printf("%ld %ld %ld", total, big, small);
}
```

this is the assembler clang trunk outputs:

```
loop():                               # @loop()
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L.str]
        mov     esi, 100
        mov     edx, 50
        mov     ecx, 50
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     printf@PLT                      # TAILCALL
.L.str:
        .asciz  "%ld %ld %ld"
```

as you can see, no loop, just the result. For longer loops clang stops doing this optimization but that's just a limitation of the compiler, other compilers could do it differently and I'm sure there is a heavily optimizing compiler out there that handles much more complex situations.

Comment: You cannot skip the loop (not for the code I provided). There is something calculated in the loop.

Comment: @ServerOverflow: Yes, but the values are not used outside the loop, so the calculation is effectively a "no-op" in that regard.

Comment: @ServerOverflow, and even if the calculations are used after the loop, a smart compiler can do the calculations and just eliminate the loop completetly. This is because all variables has known values before the loop.

Comment: @ahnlabb - Of course, they are used after the loop: I show them on the screen. I have mentioned that in my post. Both in Julia and Delphi. I do this especially to make sure that the compiler does not "super" optimize the loop :)

Comment: @ServerOverflow: Not in the code you provided in the question...

Comment: @ServerOverflow I'm not saying that you're not using the variables, I've updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: @ahnlabb - Ok, I see now what you mean :) ... However, this will excuse the Delphi compiler for being so slow :) If Julia can do that optimization, then Delphi can do it also. On the other hand, this means that there is a chance that in more "real-world" situations, Julia will not be able to use such tricks and the speed difference between Delphi and Julia might be smaller. But could be just my wishful thinking also :)

Comment: @ahnlabb - Interesting: in CompilerExplorer, change the **(long i = 0; i < 100; ++i)** to **(long i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)** and the compiler won't be able to apply the optimization trick.