# I want to obtain the ASM (Intel assembly) code generated by Julia

Tags: delphi, julia, compiler-optimization, execution-time

I wrote a simple `for` loop in Delphi and translated it to Julia. The execution time of the Delphi program, compared with the Julia one, is just pathetic: Julia is 7 times faster - [see the program and the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201947/poorly-generated-asm-code-can-it-be-improved).

I am trying to figure out how this is possible, because Delphi was supposed to be one of the fastest languages on the planet!

I want to compare the ASM code generated by Julia with the ASM code generated by Delphi. In Delphi, I need only one click to get that code. Where I can see the ASM code for a specific function in Julia?

```
using BenchmarkTools
println("----------- Test for loops")
# test for loops
function for_fun(a)
    total = 0
    big = 0
    small = 0
    for i in 1:a
        total += 1
        if i > 500000
            big += 1
        else
            small += 1
        end    
    end   

    return (total, small, big)
end

res_for = for_fun(1000000000)
println(res_for)
@btime for_fun(1000000000)
```

Comment: "Delphi was supposed to be one of the fastest languages on the planet!" Don't believe marketing hype, this has never been the case.

Comment: *because Delphi was supposed to be one of the fastest languages on the planet!* Lolwhat?  Maybe in development time?  Stack Overflow Q&As about it often show its compiler making pretty dumb asm, or mention the fact that they want to use inline asm because the compiler doesn't do a good job on things that GCC and clang would have no problem with in C or C++.  I think it's fairly well known that Delphi's optimizer is far worse than state of the art GCC and clang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `@code_native` macro applied to the function call. Here's an example

```
julia> @code_native 1+1
        .text
        .file   "+"
        .globl  "julia_+_13305"                 # -- Begin function julia_+_13305
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   "julia_+_13305",@function
"julia_+_13305":                        # @"julia_+_13305"
; ┌ @ int.jl:87 within `+`
        .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:                                # %top
        leaq    (%rdi,%rsi), %rax
        retq
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   "julia_+_13305", .Lfunc_end0-"julia_+_13305"
        .cfi_endproc
; └
                                        # -- End function
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Comment: The suffixes added on to the more common versions of the instructions you are probably familiar with tell you the width - `q` means 64 bit. It is [GNU assembly syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GNU_assembly_syntax).

Comment: It could be added that if *intel assembly* is required, one should use the `syntax` parameter: `@code_native syntax=:intel 1+1`