# How to generate assembly from Julia code on the command line?

Tags: assembly, julia

I see there is this macro [`@code_native`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75202123/i-want-to-obtain-the-asm-intel-assembly-code-generated-by-julia), which you can use like:

```
julia> @code_native 1+1
        .text
        .file   "+"
        .globl  "julia_+_13305"                 # -- Begin function julia_+_13305
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   "julia_+_13305",@function
"julia_+_13305":                        # @"julia_+_13305"
; ┌ @ int.jl:87 within `+`
        .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:                                # %top
        leaq    (%rdi,%rsi), %rax
        retq
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   "julia_+_13305", .Lfunc_end0-"julia_+_13305"
        .cfi_endproc
; └
                                        # -- End function
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

How do you take a source Julia file or text, and run it through this function to get the output assembly as text? Can it be done on the command line somehow? Something like

```
$ julia --emit-asm file.jl -o file.asm # and it outputs the assembly to another file.asm
```

I have never used julia but curious about how you can compile it (and I'd like to play with the generated assembly).

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Linux? If so sending stdout to a file works for me, i.e. if I have the following file called `code_native_out.jl` which contains:

```
@code_native 1+1
```

And I then run this with Julia but redirect stdout to a file:

```bash
julia <code_native_out.jl >code_native_out.txt
```

The output file `code_native_out.txt` contains what was printed at the REPL (the output from the `code_native` macro).

Alternatively you can capture what the macro is showing you at the REPL within Julia itself by doing something like:

```
open("code_native_out.txt","w") do io
    redirect_stdout(io) do
        @code_native 1+1
    end
end
```

Either way results in the same output file, so pick whatever works best for you.

Edit: if you have something more complicated than just the example shown, you can still do the same thing. For example:

```
function f(x) #some more complicated function you want to see
    x = 2*x
    x = x+7
    x = "the value of x is $x"
    return x
end

open("code_native_out.txt","w") do io
    redirect_stdout(io) do
        @code_native f(3)
    end
end
```

This will then spit out the assembly for all of the code evaluated for `f(3)`. If you have a function in another file you want to test, simply include that file first and then you have access to all functions declared there and you can do the same thing:

```
include("my_file_with_f.jl") #external file that contains function f(x)
open("code_native_out.txt","w") do io
    redirect_stdout(io) do
        @code_native f(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: I am on a mac, but I will also be doing this on linux, so if you know how in all environments that would be ideal.

Comment: This still means I have to put the script inside that macro...

Comment: what is the issue there? Just wrap whatever you want to see in assembly in a function, and call the macro on the function.

Comment: How can you compile to assembly more than just a function, but the whole program?

Comment: wrap the program in a function? i.e. `main(....)`
Otherwise you would need to read the code in from the other file line by line and pass it to something like this, but you'd have to check if each line was part of a function, for loop, etc. and handle all those cases differently? But calling the program from Julia inside of a `main()` seems like a much better approach -- is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: Can you show how that might look with an example? Sorry I am new to julia and just want to make sure I have what you're saying right.

Comment: Happy to provide a more explicit example -- maybe you can provide an example of the kind of file/program you want to ingest and I'll use that in creating an example? The simplest is if inside of file y you have a bunch of instructions that get executed, you can just type `include("y.jl")` and it will execute all of those instructions. So you would put that inside of the `redirect_stdout` bit in the answer above. But it could be more complicated depending on what you're actually trying to input, so if you can provide an example of an input file that would help a lot!